# Ubuntu, Vim, and the solarized color palette

Tags: vim, ubuntu, colors, terminal

I'd really like to get in on all the colorful goodness of the [solarized colorscheme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized), but I can't seem to get it configured just right.

I have the main solarized file in my *.vim/colors* folder, I've set my terminal profile colors to what is listed on the site, and I've added the lines

```
 set background=dark
 let g:solarized_termcolors=16
 colorscheme solarized
```

to my *.vimrc* file, but Vim looks greyed out and is using a bright green color as the default. How can I do it?

Comment: this might be useful to you [issue][1]


  [1]: https://superuser.com/questions/311370/solarized-colors-in-vim-dont-seem-to-be-working-for-me/968594#968594

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Here's my recommendation for things to try:

1. ensure `syntax on` is in your *.vimrc* file
2. Check what t_Co Vim has picked up from your term emulator (a quick `:echo &t_Co`). If it's 8, you'll want to `se t_Co=16`. You might also try `se t_Co=256` though without `let g:solarized_termcolors=16` this will use the 256 fallback mode, which isn't quite the correct color scheme.

Comment: Holy crap, didn't expect an answer from the author! Thanks altercation, I'll try your recommendations and shoot you an email later today.

Comment: t_Co is what was the problem on my Ubuntu box too. I installed the gnome-terminal-colors-solarized package, but it wasn't using the right background color. se t_Co=16 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: order apparently matters as well.  i found that set t_Co=16 after colorscheme solarized doesn't work.  you have to set t_Co before the colorscheme.

Comment: I find my blank/empty lines are not the same background color. How do i fix this?

Comment: I do `syntax on`, `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`, `set background=dark` and `colorscheme solarized` but it’s not quite correct. Also I use Pathogen.

Answer (score 42):

`set t_Co=16` and `let g:solarized_termcolors=16` did not work for me. This is what worked:

```
syntax on
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set t_Co=256 
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

Comment: I needed syntax on *before* the rest (I had it after) plus let g:solarized_termcolors=256 . Thanks!

Comment: I spent two hours trying to figure this out, turns out solarized_termcolors=256 was my problem -AND- that it must appear before changing the colorscheme.

Answer (score 19):

I found out how do do it from [this](http://xorcode.com/guides/solarized-vim-eclipse-ubuntu/) article.

I wrote the following script to do the gnome-terminal stuff.

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_background" --type bool false
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_colors" --type bool false
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/palette" --type string "#070736364242:#D3D301010202:#858599990000:#B5B589890000:#26268B8BD2D2:#D3D336368282:#2A2AA1A19898:#EEEEE8E8D5D5:#00002B2B3636:#CBCB4B4B1616:#58586E6E7575:#65657B7B8383:#838394949696:#6C6C7171C4C4:#9393A1A1A1A1:#FDFDF6F6E3E3"
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color" --type string "#00002B2B3636"
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color" --type string "#838394949696"
```

Comment: I think the foreground colour on a dark background should be "base0" not "base00". So the last line should be `gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color" --type string "#838394949696"`

Comment: Ahh, you know, i always thought that was off. Thanks!

Comment: it fixed the issue but messed up the original colors of files and folders....i wanted solarized only in vim or at least keep the highlight of folders and files(executables) now everything looks the same..any workaround?

Comment: The article you linked to in your answer is no longer available. This answer now lacks necessary context/explanation.

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to use Vim with solarized inside of [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux), this is the fix for your issue:

*[Fix solarized theme in tmux](https://github.com/krisleech/vimfiles/wiki/Fix-solarized-theme-in-tmux)*

Comment: This. This worked perfectly for me after just over an hour of looking around. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Trying it out myself, it seems to work better without the

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=16
```

Setting it to 16, I get the bright green color you seem to describe.  Maybe try leaving it at the default of 256?

This doesn't, however, perfectly mimic the colors from the screenshots (although the light version looks fairly close).  I only get the colors with the screenshot if I use [gVim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29#Interface).

I didn't use the terminal profile colors provided, however, so you may get a different result.

Answer (score 3):

For the copy and paste lovers, this is how you install the solarized Vim colorscheme on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install wget unzip curl
cd
wget http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/files/solarized.zip
unzip solarized.zip
mkdir .vim
mkdir .vim/colors/
mv solarized/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
cp .vimrc .vimrc.old
echo "syntax enable" > .vimrc
echo "set background=dark" >> .vimrc
echo "colorscheme solarized" >> .vimrc
curl https://raw.github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized/master/dircolors.256dark > ~/.dircolors
source .bashrc
rm -r solarized
rm solarized.zip
```

And presto.

Answer (score 3):

From the [README](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized) (*emphasis* mine):

> #### IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS:
>
> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI
> version  like gvim or macvim), **please please please** consider
> setting your terminal  emulator's colorscheme to used the Solarized
> palette. I've included palettes  for some popular terminal emulator as
> well as Xdefaults in the official  Solarized download available from
> [Solarized homepage]. If you use  Solarized *without* these colors,
> Solarized will need to be told to degrade its colorscheme to a set
> compatible with the limited 256 terminal palette (whereas  by using
> the terminal's 16 ansi color values, you can set the correct, specific
> values for the Solarized palette).
>
> If you do use the custom terminal colors, solarized.vim should work
> out of the box for you. If you are using a terminal emulator that
> supports 256 colors and  don't want to use the custom Solarized
> terminal colors, you will need to use  the degraded 256 colorscheme.
> To do so, simply add the following line *before*  the `colorschem solarized` line:
>
> ```
> let g:solarized_termcolors=256
> ```
>
> Again, *I recommend just changing your terminal colors to Solarized
> values  either manually or via one of the many terminal schemes
> available for import*.

Simply selecting Solarized for both "Text and Background Color" (choose light or dark) and "Palette" in *Terminal* → *Preferences* → *Profiles* → (select yours) → *Edit* → *Colors* worked for me on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) with the included *Terminal* application.

Some other answers recommend choosing a 256 color palette but, as mentioned in the documentation, this gives you a degraded (and visibly worse in my opinion) color scheme.

Comment: Selecting the palette was the part that I missed at first.

Comment: For clarity, "Terminal > Preferences" means "Right click on terminal and select preferences"

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me for [exherbo](http://exherbo.org)

```
git clone https://github.com/sigurdga/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized
cd gnome-terminal-colors-solarized
sh install.sh -s dark -p <my_current_profile>
```

[256 colors in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim) may also help

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I was using the Solarized Dark gnome-terminal scheme that Ubuntu ships with, and while it looked fine in the shell itself, Vim looked like a mess. Some of the other answers here (tweaking Vim config) helped get it close to right, but the background color was still black or grey, rather than the slate-blue it's supposed to be. Installing this replacement gnome-terminal colorscheme fixed it with my default Vim config.