# VIM Solarized colorscheme with ubuntu terminal

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I am trying to get the solarized colorscheme to work. But there seems I have to do something else then putting this few lines in my .vimrc:

```
syntax enable
let g:solarized_termcolors=256                                                  
set background=dark                                                             
colorscheme solarized
```

But when I put the line with termcolor:256 in.Then I dont see any colors.
Without it every color has a bad backgroundcolor :/

I am running the latest linux mint with the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu, vim, and the solarized color palette](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560658/ubuntu-vim-and-the-solarized-color-palette)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable 256 colors in vim:

```
set t_Co=256
```