# solarized theme in vim (and MATE Terminal?) doesnt work properly

Tags: vim, debian, mate

I just downloaded the solarized theme for vim and for the mate terminal and am now desperately trying to set them up.

I've kinda got the light theme on MATE Terminal running (as stated in the description of solarized theme the dark theme is work in progress) but don't see any other colors then the normal text color and am now wondering if this is as intended (and how to properly test this)...

In vim I'd like to run the dark theme, but if I do as described on the page (https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) it doesn't work. I just get results like this:

http://s12.postimg.org/51e9g7uvh/Selection_001.png

Im kinda new to linux so I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: Recomended reading: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560658/ubuntu-vim-and-the-solarized-color-palette) on SO.

Comment: That did the job :D Thanks a ton :)

Comment: You know, answer from the author :)

Comment: do you know any MATE Terminal command, that generates red text (or just with a different color)? I'd like to test if the light Theme is working correctly in the Terminal

Comment: To change e.g. your prompt to red `$ export PS1="\e[1;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "` (Light red `1;31`, Red `0;31`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ryuichiro suggested: [Ubuntu, vim, and the solarized color palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560658/ubuntu-vim-and-the-solarized-color-palette)